# html tags showing in content

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

My database contains data like:

> &lt;b&gt;&lt;a href="[LINK]"&gt;You&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/b&gt; have a confirmed seat in the event &lt;b&gt;&lt;a href="[LINK]"&gt;[TITLE]&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/b&gt;<br>

when i display this it appears as:

> `<b> <a href="[LINK]">You</a></b> have a confirmed seat in the event <b><a href="[LINK]">[TIT`

the text is broken and the html tags are also shown

> i tried html_entity_decode()

Please help
thankyou

Comment: In which you are displaying it? you should try textarea or textbox instead.

Comment: In what way did `html_entity_decode()` not work?

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is an issue you have and you just put it in here without doing any kind of research. That's not what is meant by professional and enthusiast programmers this website has in it's description. Please do not make yourself smaller than you are and please keep this a community site and not your personal problem forum.

Comment: i am just pulling the data from database and echo it inside <p> tag

Comment: And it works perfectly. If it's not what you want, tell us what you _do_ want, and why the database contains data that you don't want to display.

Comment: @MrLister there are many templates like this in my DB and depending on situation i pull the required one and send to user... the only problem is the html tags are being displayed, they are not functioning
i don't wan't user to get this: <b> <a href="[LINK]">You</a></b> have a confirmed seat in the event <b><a href="[LINK]">[TITLE]</a> </b>...instead they should get only : You have a confirmed seat in the event

Comment: OK, and should they get the clickable link ("You") or only the plain text?

Comment: @MrLister it should be clickable

Comment: @AJ In that case, Mystics answer should do what you want, so I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: found the ans:   html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($string))

Answer (score 2):

Just use **htmlspecialchars_decode**

```
htmlspecialchars_decode( '[...]', ENT_QUOTES );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using htmlspecialchars() while saving data to database and htmlspecialchars_decode() while displaying data to browser.
Hope this help you.
```

Comment: done this but not working

Answer (score 0):

```
function cleanMyDirtyData( $dirty_dirty_data ){
return mysql_real_escape_string( htmlentities( $dirty_dirty_data, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8' ) );
}
```

Try to use this function, before you write data to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever response you are getting from server just pass it to javascript.

In Javascript,

```
var p = document.getElementById('pID');
p.textContent = "Your text from backend here";
```

In jQuery,

```
$('#idName').text("Your text from backend here");
```

I don't know whether it could be done using PHP as I am not in to that field.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/ZM6zG/)